# Handling exceptions on a Pool of Requests

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle to send a number of requests to an API endpoint, using the `Pool` functionality to send these asynchronously and concurrently.

The script looks like this:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;
use GuzzleHttp\Pool;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

/* Configure logger */
Logger::configure("config/logger.xml");
$logger = Logger::getLogger("console");

/* Configure Guzzle Client */
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://my.api/',
    'timeout' => 2.0,
    'allow_redirects' => false,
]);

/* Anonymous function (closure) to 'yield' X number of Requests */
$requests = function ($num_requests) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_requests; $i++) {
        yield new Request('GET', "/MY_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER/");
    }
};

/* Create a Pool for the above requests */
$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(20), [
    'concurrency' => 5,  // Determine how many requests to send concurrently
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
        $logger->info('$index: ' . $index . ', $response: ' . $response);
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
        try {
            echo $reason;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_WARNING);
        }
    },
]);

/* Initiate transfers/create a promise */
$promise = $pool->promise();

/* Force the pool of requests to complete */
$promise->wait();
```

Basically, send 20 requests (5 at a time) to `http://my.api/MY_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER`.

The `Pool` appears to work. If I add an `echo` to the `rejected` requests, I get output like:

```
#0 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(149): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(102): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#2 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php(181): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
#3 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php(110): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler->processMessages()
#4 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php(125): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler->tick()
#5 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(246): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler->execute(true)
#6 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(223): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn()
#7 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(267): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#8 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(225): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList()
#9 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#10 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/EachPromise.php(101): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait()
#11 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(246): GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise->GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}(true)
#12 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(223): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn()
#13 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#14 /Users/me/guzzle-POC/poc.php(50): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait()
#15 {main}GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: my.api (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in /Users/me/guzzle-POC/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:185
```

The main problem here being `#15`, `Could not resolve host: my.api`. This is expected behaviour, but **I want to catch this exception**.

The `try/catch` that I've used just doesn't work at all - it catches nothing.

Presumably this is because of the Pool's asynchronous nature, but is it possible to catch these exceptions in any way?

All I want to achieve basically is, `if can't resolve; log error and continue with other requests`-type approach.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, I would share a solution which worked for me.
Taking example from your question,

This is the picture which gives the tree heirarchy of guzzle exception(source Guzzle Docs.)
[image: Source: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#exceptions]

Also `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException` exception is thrown in the event of a networking error and also `ConnectException` does not have an associated response, so therefore there is no 400 or 500 error. So it should give false for `hasResponse()`

---

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://my.api/',
    'timeout' => 2.0,
    'allow_redirects' => false,
]);

/* Anonymous function (closure) to 'yield' X number of Requests */
$requests = function ($num_requests) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_requests; $i++) {
        yield new Request('GET', "/MY_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER/");
    }
};

/* Create a Pool for the above requests */
$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(20), [
    'concurrency' => 5,  // Determine how many requests to send concurrently
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
        $logger->info('$index: ' . $index . ', $response: ' . $response);
    },
    'rejected' => function (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\TransferException $reason, $index) {
            if ($reason->hasResponse()){
            // this will mainly catch RequestException(Exception with statuscode and responses)
                    if ($reason->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '400') {
                        // log your exception
                    } elseif($reason->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '403'){
                        //log your unauthorised code exception 
                    }else{
                        //similarly log your other status code exception 
                    }
            } else{ 
                // ConnectException should come here, you can log it, will not have any responses as the request was never sent.
            }
    },
]);

/* Initiate transfers/create a promise */
$promise = $pool->promise();

/* Force the pool of requests to complete */
$promise->wait();
```

#### Demerits

You need to know the exact status code of your exceptions.

---

Also if someone is specific to only catch ServerException or ClientException, then they can replace TransferException with other exception down the heirarchy tree.

```
'rejected' => function (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $reason, $index) {
```