# Throwing an instance of RequestException while Mocking in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, guzzle

I wanna mock an api with success and failed results, while the request failing will throw `RequestException` but I cannot use It cause it's asking for arguments like response and stuff but other Exceptions like `ConnectionException` will happen without needing additional parameters. any thoughts?

```
$wrongOtp = 12345;

$this->instance(Some::class, Mockery::mock(Some::class, function (Mockery\MockInterface $mock) use ($wrongOtp) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('getProfile')->with($this->ssn, $wrongOtp, $this->track_code)
        ->andThrow(RequestException::class)->once();
}));
```

so If I replace `RequestException` with `ConnectionException` in my code above it will run the test without problem but if I use `RequestException` it asks for a response as first argument and I actually don't know which type of response should I provide for it.

Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: see the heirarchy of Exceptions in guzzle, ConnectException is not asking for a response as it does not have any response, ConnectException is thrown when guzzle is not able to connect with server, so no connection data not send so no response, in place all 400 to 500 range response i.e bad responses are handled by RequestException i.e why it gives you response.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65747999/9471283 for an example & exceptions in guzzle docs for more details